# FPDF how to center a table in document

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using FPDF to build pdf files via PHP. I want to make a centered cell with fractions. But I am unable to do so using Cell og multicell. Textbox also. Is there some way to achieve this? I could imaging that it is a table centered on the middle of the page. and then auto width makes it align in the middle. But I can't seem to achieve it with cells at the moment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by create new extend class from fpdf which to write HTML code and save it as WriteHTML.php

```html
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF_HTML extends FPDF
{
    var $B=0;
    var $I=0;
    var $U=0;
    var $HREF='';
    var $ALIGN='';

    function WriteHTML($html)
    {
        //HTML parser
        $html=str_replace("\n",' ',$html);
        $a=preg_split('/<(.*)>/U',$html,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        foreach($a as $i=>$e)
        {
            if($i%2==0)
            {
                //Text
                if($this->HREF)
                    $this->PutLink($this->HREF,$e);
                elseif($this->ALIGN=='center')
                    $this->Cell(0,5,$e,0,1,'C');
                else
                    $this->Write(5,$e);
            }
            else
            {
                //Tag
                if($e[0]=='/')
                    $this->CloseTag(strtoupper(substr($e,1)));
                else
                {
                    //Extract properties
                    $a2=explode(' ',$e);
                    $tag=strtoupper(array_shift($a2));
                    $prop=array();
                    foreach($a2 as $v)
                    {
                        if(preg_match('/([^=]*)=["\']?([^"\']*)/',$v,$a3))
                            $prop[strtoupper($a3[1])]=$a3[2];
                    }
                    $this->OpenTag($tag,$prop);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function OpenTag($tag,$prop)
    {
        //Opening tag
        if($tag=='B' || $tag=='I' || $tag=='U')
            $this->SetStyle($tag,true);
        if($tag=='A')
            $this->HREF=$prop['HREF'];
        if($tag=='BR')
            $this->Ln(5);
        if($tag=='P')
            $this->ALIGN=$prop['ALIGN'];
        if($tag=='HR')
        {
            if( !empty($prop['WIDTH']) )
                $Width = $prop['WIDTH'];
            else
                $Width = $this->w - $this->lMargin-$this->rMargin;
            $this->Ln(2);
            $x = $this->GetX();
            $y = $this->GetY();
            $this->SetLineWidth(0.4);
            $this->Line($x,$y,$x+$Width,$y);
            $this->SetLineWidth(0.2);
            $this->Ln(2);
        }
    }

    function CloseTag($tag)
    {
        //Closing tag
        if($tag=='B' || $tag=='I' || $tag=='U')
            $this->SetStyle($tag,false);
        if($tag=='A')
            $this->HREF='';
        if($tag=='P')
            $this->ALIGN='';
    }

    function SetStyle($tag,$enable)
    {
        //Modify style and select corresponding font
        $this->$tag+=($enable ? 1 : -1);
        $style='';
        foreach(array('B','I','U') as $s)
            if($this->$s>0)
                $style.=$s;
        $this->SetFont('',$style);
    }

    function PutLink($URL,$txt)
    {
        //Put a hyperlink
        $this->SetTextColor(0,0,255);
        $this->SetStyle('U',true);
        $this->Write(5,$txt,$URL);
        $this->SetStyle('U',false);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
    }
}
?>
```

You can created the pdf like sampe below

```html
<?php
require('WriteHTML.php');

$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->WriteHTML('You can<br><p align="center">center a line</p>and add a horizontal rule:<br><hr>');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

For more information about this writeHTML please visit  http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script41.php

Or you can try another similar writeHTML here
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php

OR another here
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script50.php

It is easy when you want to center your paragraph / text when using HTML Code.

Hope this will help you.